# Model name of sub controller in ApplicationController method

Tags: model, controller, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to define a method on my application controller which I can then call from any controller which inherits from it. Inside this method, I need to be able to get the model object associated with whichever controller is calling the method.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def bar
    #Access model name here. So inside FooController, it would have Foo.
  end
end

class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    bar #Use the method here
  end
end
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
self.class.to_s.chomp "Controller"
```